# VS code not detecting library (opencv) from vcpkg on linux. How can I link it?

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

my c_cpp_properties.json config has the path to vcpkg in it.

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "${vcpkgRoot}/x64-linux/include/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu17",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
            "compilerArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and I have the library installed:

```
[alexander@alexanderThinkPad vcpkg]$ ./vcpkg install opencv
Computing installation plan...
The following packages are already installed:
    opencv[core,dnn,jpeg,png,tiff,webp]:x64-linux -> 4.3.0#1
Package opencv:x64-linux is already installed
```

however the library is not detected though navigating to the correct directory shows that the file opencv.hpp is present. How can I get VS code to recognize the library?